# Geography Data Import

Tags: sql-server, bcp, sqlgeography

I'm trying to import geography data from a CSV file in to SQL server using the bcp (bulk copy tool) but I can't figure out the format. I would like to use something like this in the CSV files but I get errors on the POINT column:

```
101932694,POINT(44.0586891174316 -69.2067337036133 4326),2014-07-30,24452353
```

How can I format geography data in the CSV file so bcp will accept it?

Answer (score 1):

OK, it could not find any information on importing human readable geography data using bcp, so I converted the point data:

POINT (44.058689117431641 -69.206733703613281 4326),...

To the binary form:

E6100000010D000000203B4D51C000000020830746400000000000E6B040,...

And put the binary form in my CSV file. bcp seemed to work fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about BCP, but hopefully this will give you what you need.

Try importing your data to a temporary table as a string, then importing it into the real table with an update.

Inside of SQL Server spatial data is stored like a varbinary, i.e. your point will be stored as

```
0xE6100000010C010000203B4D51C0FAFFFF1F83074640
```

If you try and move the data with SSIS, it actually treats it as varbinary, not as spatial.  Because of this, a conversion is required to get your string into the correct format.

```
SELECT GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(44.0586891174316 -69.2067337036133)', 4326)
or
SELECT GEOGRAPHY::Point(-69.2067337036133,44.0586891174316,4326)
```

For those reasons, I am guessing BCP does not implicitly recognize the conversion, and you will probably need to do it manually.

CSV => Temp Table =>

```
INSERT INTO RealTable (GeogColumn) SELECT GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(GeogString,4326) FROM TempTable
```

Comment: OK. I found a reference to the binary format. I think I will try converting my text data "point(x y)" to the binary format and putting that in to the CSV file. If that does not work, I'll try hcaelxxam suggestion.